# mysql.createConnection is not a function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have tested all the answers I saw here but none changes the final result, after running this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : '**',
    user     : '**',
    password : '**',
    database : '**'
  });
  connection.connect();
```

I end up withthe same problem:

```
/home/pi/node_modules/mysql.js:2


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                         ^

TypeError: mysql.createConnection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/mysql.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Comment: how are you running your code ?

Comment: node mysql.js in the cmd box

Comment: As per my guess, your mysql import is not working. Try console.log(mysql) after the import statement, and see if it is imported properly. Post that try installing mysql module once again.

Comment: {}
(node:6908) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6908) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'constructor' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6908) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6908) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of module exports inside circular dependency

Comment: What can I do to make Node to correctly import the mysql?

Comment: Your module is not installed properly, make sure your mysql folder inside node_modules directory has files. Else try to remove your mysql dependency and install it again using "npm i mysql"

Comment: I reinstalled and the problem still persisted still I moved the file from  \node_modules\ into \node_modules\mysql
Now works, but is there a way to run in the main folder, I need other modules to run in the the same script.